# jquery .html() doesnt load width and height synchronously

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to center a div, here is what i came up so far:

```
function miniWindow(content) {
    $('#miniWindow').hide();
    $('#miniWindow').css({'top' : '280px', 'left' : '385px'}); //start position
    $('#miniContent').html(content); //<-- the problem line

    //center the div
    setTimeout( function() {
            var width = $('#miniWindow').outerWidth();
            var height = $('#miniWindow').outerHeight();
            $('#miniWindow').css({'left' : '-='+width/2, 'top' : '-='+height/2});
            $('#miniWindow').show();
    }, 1000);
}

miniWindow('fubar'); //invoke
```

The problem is that I need a timeout to give the .html() function time to set width and height although .html() should be synchronous!?

Is there any other solution without using timeout to solve this problem?

Comment: which markup contains `content` variable? do you append images?

Comment: i just use html or text but images would be acceptable too :)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan.  See last line `miniWindow('fubar'); //invoke`

Comment: When do you call `miniWindow`?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli. See last line `miniWindow('fubar'); //invoke` (2nd take)

Comment: @DidierGhys - I know, but is it on page load or window load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

outerHeight() and innerHeight() don't work on hidden elements.

Try calling `$('#miniWindow').show()` before setting the position (and getting the width/height).

Comment: I think you are correct (http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) - ".outerHeight() don't works with hidden elements like .height() method :("